# Git not saving the staged, commited, and pushed changes of a branch

Tags: git

I thought I was familiar with git basics until I came across this:

I am in `master`. All is staged, commited, and pushed (via SourceTree and re-confirmed via TerminalBash, as I am obsessed with both).

I create a new branch called `micwatson` (via bash commands: `git checkout -b micwatson`) so now I am in it, make changes, stage, commit, and push (via SourceTree and re-confirmed via TerminalBash) and then switch back to `master` via SourceTree by double-clicking.

In both branches, before switching, I always check with `git status` to make sure all is clean, as well as SourceTree.

Once I am back in `master`, all of a sudden, `git status` is not showing a clean bill, the same is shown on SourceTree, and instead pointing out **all the changes from the other branch (micwatson) as untracked**...

I am really confused. Why does this happen? Please see screenshot showing the state of SourceTree. By the way, as silly as it may sound, usually when you start off with `master` in SourceTree, it is blue and then when you branch off, those branches are in different colors. When this happened, all my previous `master` commit nodes turned pink and the branch turned blue. Not sure if that means anything at all, but it is the opposite of what I have seen so far...

[image]

Comment: Please include the _exact_ steps/commands you took to arrive back in `master`, in the state you described.  Most likely, you took a wrong turn somewhere.

Comment: I added the basic commands I used and some through SourceTree, by editing the question.

Comment: Maybe run through that and screenshot the terminal with all output.

Comment: What are the changes you made in the `micwatson` branch?

Comment: Did you forget to `git add` any new files?

Comment: No, I never forget, because I usually add/stage them via terminal and then look at the graphical results in SourceTree, so I always make double-sure that all is added and commited and pushed to the right branch, etc... In my other branch, I created a new Unity3D scene with a new character, and quickly added and commited and pushed, because I commit often. That is why I am sooo confused at this strange behavior...

Comment: This sounds like SourceTree (apparently a GUI) not "playing well" with command-line Git. That would be unsurprising to me: GUI authors often think that they are gods and that nothing happens without them knowing or doing it. :-) This is one of many reasons I avoid GUIs when possible, so I'm just speculating here.

Comment: Check if the files showing up as untracked when in master are 'ignored' files in micwatson (i.e. not tracked in micwatson because of changes to micwatson's gitignore)?

Comment: @ack_inc Thanks for the tip. There is only one gitignore file in my repo, so I don't think that would be the cause.

Comment: @torek Thanks! So, would you recommend everything is always done via bash and then maybe just visually checked/inspected via SourceTree?

Comment: I always use `git add --all` to stage absolutely everything, including deletions. Is this the most all-comprehensive for adding?

Comment: @Joshua - that one .gitignore might have different contents in master and micwatson. The basic idea I'm getting at is that files untracked by micwatson (due to its gitignore contents) are not going to be removed from your working directory when you switch to master (and will therefore show up as untracked files in master)

Comment: Well, that's more or less my method, except that I don't have SourceTree at all, so I can't ever run it. I sometimes use gitk to view Git commits, especially in unfamiliar repositories.