# Visual Branching in SourceTree

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

Using the basic git commands, when I am in my `master` branch, via TerminalBash, I create a new branch (`git checkout -b twomics`) and then stage and commit and push, but I do not see the **branching** in SourceTree. Why is that?

I have attached an image. It does not make a difference whether I choose the `All Branches` or `Current Branch` tab...

I have had other issues with this (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53745563/git-not-saving-the-staged-commited-and-pushed-changes-of-a-branch) post) so I am wondering if it is just me or am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Git branch is a pointer to a commit. Both branches (`master` and `twomics`) are clearly visible in the screenshot you posted.

Because `twomics` started from `master` and `master` didn't change its position since you have created `twomics` (more exactly, there is no new commit added on `master`), a Git graphic client does not have any reason to show divergent branches (as in "tree branches") on the graph.

Your branches did not diverge. All project history included in the `master` branch is also included in the `twomics` change. `master` is an ancestor of `twomics`.

---

The `twomics` branch is two commits ahead of `master`. Merging `twomics` into `master` can be done using "fast-forward" because the two branches did not diverge.

A "fast-forward" merge means the target branch (`master` here) is pushed forward until it reaches the source branch (`twomics`). This type of merge is possible only when the target branch is an ancestor of the source branch (and it is the default type of merge when it is possible).